# Is there a Visualization of sets other than Venn diagram?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a visualization of sets other than Venn diagram?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "better" ? A Venn diagram is a good way of showing the possible intersections between a small family of sets, but it becomes difficult to draw if you want to show all possible intersections for more than $3$ sets.

Comment: Is there any other way to represent intersection of more than three sets?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in Venn Diagram's closely related cousin, [Euler Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram).

From Wikipedia:

> An Euler diagram  is a diagrammatic means of representing sets and their relationships. Typically they involve overlapping shapes, and may be scaled, such that the area of the shape is proportional to the number of elements it contains. They are particularly useful for explaining complex hierarchies and overlapping definitions. They are often confused with Venn diagrams. Unlike Venn diagrams, which show all possible relations between different sets, the Euler diagram shows only relevant relationships.
>
> [image: diagram]